# Why show all data from mysql databese if I hit saarch button by keep search field blank and need extra one HTML button for all Entries.?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search-form

When i keep search field blank and hit on search button, then show all results from  mysql database, Why.... here is my php code....

I want to create it, when i keep search field blank and click search button... have to show error "no search result" and want to create disallowed white spacing search and need extra one HTML button for all Entries. By one click so that i get all entries......

please help me....

```
 <?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost', '1093913', 'tanim1996');
$db=mysql_select_db('1093913');



if(isset($_POST['button'])){    //trigger button click

  $search=$_POST['search'];

  $query=mysql_query("select * from iconic19 where student_id like '%{$search}%' || name like '%{$search}%' || phone like '%{$search}%' || blood like '%{$search}%' || district like '%{$search}%' ");



if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {                 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

 echo "<tbody>";
               echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td data-label='Student ID'>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
               echo "<td data-label='Name' style='font-weight:bold;' >".$row['name']."</td>";
                 echo "<td data-label='Mobile No'>"."<a href='tel:".$row['phone']."'>".$row['phone']."</a>"."</td>";
                echo "<td data-label='Blood' style='color:red; font-weight:bold;' >".$row['blood']."</td>";
                echo "<td data-label='Email'>"."<a href='mailto:".$row['email']."'>".$row['email']."</a>"."</td>";
                echo "<td data-label='District'>".$row['district']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";

  }
}else{
    echo "<div class='error-text'>No results</div><br><br>";
  }

}else{                          //while not in use of search  returns all the values
  $query=mysql_query("select * from iconic19");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {



  }


}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Its Html Code

```
<form id="nbc-searchblue1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <input id='wc-searchblueinput1' placeholder="Search Iconic..." name="search" type="search" autofocus>
    <br>
    <input id='nbc-searchbluesubmit1' value="Search" type="submit" name="button">

   <div class="view-all"> <a href="script.php">Show all</a></div>

</form>
```

Its css Code..

```
.view-all a {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Add to your first if && !empty($_POST['search']) would solve the problem

Comment: But, In first IF is associated  with ['button'] ?

Comment: Its  show this error line........

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting '(' in /home/vhosts/sample.com/search.php on line 8

Comment: if(isset($_POST['button']) AND !empty($_POST['search'])) {

Comment: Thanks. Its worked, but not show any error msg....?

Comment: i will add an answer, its easier to clean up your code a bit

Comment: Hey, TobiasHH,  I need once more help, I need to create one individual button to show all info from database by one click except search button. But How,,,,,,? 


NB. I am new to PHP. That's why i need some help.

Comment: Hmm u want all entries but exclude the ones from the search button or just all entries?

Comment: I want all entries by one click . Need a button where i click and then show all entries....Its just a extra one button for all entries
but search button also need for search individually...

Comment: Can u edit your post, with your new html button u want?

Comment: Yes, Its Done, I edited my post and add line for HTML button.

Comment: I don't see your edit in the code as I wanted. You didnt need to change the title and the question. but just add an <a href="yourscript.php">Show all</a> and design it with css. So it goes into your else block.

Comment: Now i add a button in HTML code....!

Comment: I was said , i need a specific button to show all data in one click, but didn't give me... please help me dear..

Comment: You need JavaScript for it, see: https://jsfiddle.net/qtvh1bL0/

Comment: But as your line, i edit html with <a> tag and add some css for it....

Comment: So we are finished?

Comment: Yes... . thanks for overall. And if I need any help in future, I hope you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost', '1093913', 'tanim1996');
$db=mysql_select_db('1093913');

if(isset($_POST['button'])){    //trigger button click
    $numRows = 0;
    if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
        $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
        $query = mysql_query("select * from iconic19 where student_id like '%{$search}%' || name like '%{$search}%' || phone like '%{$search}%' || blood like '%{$search}%' || district like '%{$search}%' ");
        $numRows = (int)mysql_num_rows($query);
    }

    if ($numRows > 0) {                 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td data-label='Student ID'>".$row['student_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td data-label='Name' style='font-weight:bold;' >".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td data-label='Mobile No'>"."<a href='tel:".$row['phone']."'>".$row['phone']."</a>"."</td>";
            echo "<td data-label='Blood' style='color:red; font-weight:bold;' >".$row['blood']."</td>";
            echo "<td data-label='Email'>"."<a href='mailto:".$row['email']."'>".$row['email']."</a>"."</td>";
            echo "<td data-label='District'>".$row['district']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";

        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='error-text'>No results</div><br><br>";
    }
} else {                          //while not in use of search  returns all the values
    $query = mysql_query("select * from iconic19");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {



    }
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

What I have done was creating a new variable $numRows with a default value of 0. If your search is empty there is no query to the database. I escaped your $search variable.

BTW: Please change to mysqli, the mysql extension is no longer supported in newer php versions.

Comment: Thnak you very much ❤, 
I need once more help, I need to create one individual button to show all info from database by one click except search button. But How I add one button for this feature,,,,,,?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `$_POST['search']` is blank then display your message else execute your query.